# Orbot Doesn't Work on Restart

Tags: orbot

I usually leave Orbot running continuously, but sometimes, I accidentally deactivate the service.  After this, it doesn't seem to create a Tor circuit.  It has the notification on my phone, but it only has this:

*Orbot/

0Kbps download/ 0Kbps upload*

Under this, it usually shows between 1 and 6 location, IPs, and name blocks, but it does not do this after.  When I open Orweb, it has either a tunnel error or a timed out error (ERR_TIMED_OUT).

I assume this also means the apps I run through the Tor proxy are not connecting to the network, and I have to reinstall.  Is there a way to prevent having to reinstall the app?